# opencv fails to capture video from ip axis camera in C++ but works in Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I can't open the video camera in C++ using Qt but I'm able to in Python for an axis camera.  It's able to display the video in Python

I was able to open a webcam and have it display video using VidoCapture cap(0);  I've tried using the same url from the database in Python and it worked in python.  Then I hard code the same rtsp url in C++ but it failed to even open the ip camera for video capture.  I've tried replacing rtsp to http but still didn't work.  I've tried putting ipAddress:port# but that didn't work either.  Also, I've tried playing a .mp4 video file, but that didn't work either using VideoCapture cap("/____/_____/_____.mp4");  Furthermore, I have tried putting my rtsp address in the browser and in VLC player and it streamed fine for both of those but not in the C++ program.

Python:

```
    url = None        
    url = channel.url
    print('channel.url: ' + url)
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(url)

    print("camera " + str(url) + " is opened : " + str(vs.isOpened()))
```

Output: 
camera rtsp://username:password@xxx.xxx.x.xx/axis-media/media.amp is opened : True

C++

```
    VideoCapture cap("rtsp://username:password@xxx.xxx.x.xx/axis-media/media.amp");

    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        qDebug() << "Failed to video capture";
    else
        qDebug() << "able to open camera";
```

Output:
Failed to video capture

I'm trying to to get to output "able to open camera" in c++. Then have it display the video of the ip camera.  I believe I have the rest of the code for that because I got it to display with the web camera.

Comment: Please run the C++ version code in release mode not in debug.

Comment: It might not be anything do do with your case but I remember having troubles with my antivirus software blocking the connection in C++. Though, that was a local webcam.

Comment: I believe I'm using release mode.  In QT I just see a play button and another play button with a bug picture on it. There's no antivirus on my machine as I'm using linux

Comment: @JasonLy No no, I mean you should select the release mode just above the play button as you said, in the list, you will see Release, Debug, and Profile options, so you select the Release option and then run the program with the play button.

Comment: I clicked on the monitor icon looking button above the play button to switch to release mode but it still didn't work